# Python code to automatically divide target objects in an image half way (too many images in a folder)

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, deep-learning, object-detection

I am new at image processing,

I have an object detection task, and I want to train a model with images that contain target objects which are not full objects. I have too many images in a folder, and each image contains more than one object. how can I automatically divide those targets in a single image, so that I can get many halves of target objects images for training my detection model? Thanks.

I tried to use Python Imaging Library (PIL) to crop multiple images from a single image, but this doesn't consider dividing an image according to different target objects that appear in a single image.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.